# Porting windows batch file to shell script. If possible execute the task in parallel

Tags: linux, bash, shell, batch-file, sh

I have this windows based version which opens my current tasks in multiple thread. Though, it opens multiple threads yet acceptable.
I want to port this to Linux? I have limited knowledge of Linux and hence hoping for someone to help here.

***clean.bat***

```
ant -DCorrelator.port="15800" clean
```

***start_parallel.bat***

```
call clean.bat
start "Engine 1500" ant -Dengine.port="15800" -Dfamily.one="true" -Dfamily.two="false" start
start "Engine 1505" ant -Dengine.port="15805" -Dfamily.one="false" -Dfamily.two="true" start
```

Comment: though, it opens multiple **command-windows** yet acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to admit, I am not sure I fully understand your scenario, but to run tasks in parallel in linux, you can put them in the backgrund using `&`.

Example:

```
start "Engine 1500" ant start &
start "Engine 1505" ant start &
```

To call your other script, simply execute it from your first shell script.

So in total you would have:

`clean.sh:`

```
#!/bin/sh
ant -DCorrelator clean
```

`start_parallel.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
clean.sh
start "Engine 1500" ant -Dengine.port="15800" -Dfamily.one="true" -Dfamily.two="false" start &
start "Engine 1505" ant -Dengine.port="15800" -Dfamily.one="false" -Dfamily.two="true" start &
```

Make sure you make both scripts executable using `chmod`:

```
chmod +x clean.sh
chmod +x start_parallel.sh
```

And Linux only looks in your path (`echo $PATH`) for executable scripts. If you want to execute scripts in a different directory, you have to give at least its relative path. If the script is in your current directory do:

```
./start_parallel.sh
```

And you would also have to call `clean.sh` as `./clean.sh` in your script. To avoid this, I suggest you put the scripts into a directory in your path, usually `/usr/local/bin/` or create a `bin` directory in your home directory and add that to your path using `for example`.profile`.

Cheers.

Comment: you almost nailed it with almost one exception
In start_parallel.sh it will not recognise windows command "start "Engine 1500" ".
I know i am being too picky. Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

**clean.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
# Note: The header above is only necessary if you intend to call the script as standalone as well.
ant -DCorrelator.port="15800" clean
```

**start_parallel.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
source ./clean.sh
konsole -p tabtitle="Engine 1500" -e ant -Dengine.port="15800" -Dfamily.one="true" -Dfamily.two="false" start
konsole -p tabtitle="Engine 1505" -e ant -Dengine.port="15805" -Dfamily.one="false" -Dfamily.two="true" start
```

It works with `konsole` but I'll try to update with other terminals.

Run with `bash start_parallel.sh`.

**Update for XTerm**

```
...
xterm -T "Engine 1500" -e ant -Dengine.port="15800" -Dfamily.one="true" -Dfamily.two="false" start &
xterm -T "Engine 1505" -e ant -Dengine.port="15805" -Dfamily.one="false" -Dfamily.two="true" start &
```